# Opening deeplink in webbrowser to React-Native application

Tags: android, react-native

I have been trying to open an application through a web browser on my Android phones (both emulator and psychical device). Anytime when I put 'mydeeplink://people/0' as URL it just starts searching on google for the query instead of opening the app.

I personally think that I didn't configure one of the Google flags correctly. I left it all on default, because I didn't found anybody mentioning flags corresponding to deep links on the internet.

I already tried adding node-tools to the intent-filter after 'android:label="filter_react_native"'

I followed a tutorial from [this website](https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e), however it seems to be outdated

this is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.mydeeplink">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native" 
     android:autoVerify="true">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="mydeeplink" android:host="people" />
  </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity 
  android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>

 </manifest>
```

index.android.js:

```
 // index.ios.js or index.android.js
 import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
 import Router from './router';
 AppRegistry.registerComponent('mydeeplink', () => Router);
```

home.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Platform, Text, Linking } from 'react-native';
class Home extends React.Component {
static navigationOptions = { // A
title: 'Home',
};
componentDidMount() { // B
 if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
  Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
  this.navigate(url);
});
} else {
  Linking.addEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
}
}

componentWillUnmount() { // C
Linking.removeEventListener('url', this.handleOpenURL);
}
handleOpenURL = (event) => { // D
this.navigate(event.url);
}
navigate = (url) => { // E
const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
const route = url.replace(/.*?:\/\//g, '');
const id = route.match(/\/([^\/]+)\/?$/)[1];
const routeName = route.split('/')[0];

if (routeName === 'people') {
  navigate('People', { id, name: 'chris' })
};
}
render() {
return <Text>Hello from Home!</Text>;
}
}
export default Home;
```

router.js:

```
       import React from 'react';
 import {
    AppRegistry,
    Text,
    }  from 'react-native';

  import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
  import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
  import Home from './home';
  import People from './people';
  const Router = createStackNavigator(
   {
      Home: Home,
      Details: People,
   },
   {
       initialRouteName: 'Home',
   }
 ) ;


const AppContainer = createAppContainer(Router);

export default class App extends React.Component{
     render(){
         return <AppContainer/>
     }
  }
```

It's expected to open my React-Native app and open a picture of Leela. Currently the query just searched for the query on the world wide web in google chrome on both emulator as physical device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was quite easy. Apparently deep links can't be opened without configuring the right chrome://flags. I didn't manage to find the right configurations so I fixed the problem in another way:

I just made a google website where you put:
     Deeplink to app

Then I simply opened the google website on my phone and pressed the link.

Very easy solution, quite hard to find since any other tutorial I found simply typed the link in the URL bar.